# Textarea is draggable in certain browsers

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I have a textarea on my web page.  It displays differently in different browsers.  I'm not too concerned about what it looks like in various browsers.  In some browsers like Firefox there is a draggable corner that I don't want there, is there a way of "switching" this off?  I set the size of the textarea using the cols and rows properties.

The doctype that I am using is strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `textarea {resize:none}` css style.  You can also use `horizontal`, `vertical` or `both` as values.

Comment: I've never actually used it so didn't bother to check, but yes, it does appear to be CSS3.

Comment: @Marek: Then what do you do if your user drags the textarea out of the border limits of your design?  Then it looks horrible.

Comment: Are you sure you meant to respond to me with this comment?  But I kind of agree with e-satis - what does it matter if the user does it?  It's a conscious decision on the part of the user and they will expect the design to look less than ideal.

Comment: But if the design looks bad won't it make the user think that the coder can't code and never return again?

Comment: @Brendan - my original answer is nothing like e-satis's reply - it will actually remove the resizing ability in CSS3 compliant browsers (seems like quite a few implement this feature)

Comment: "But if the design looks bad won't it make the user think that the coder can't code and never return again? " if it looks like crap when I first load the page, maybe.  If it looks like crap because I (as a user) intentionally broke it - of course not.

Comment: Resize the comment textarea on Stackoverflow to the right. It breaks everything. Still, SO is known for its ergonomics, as much as it's good content.

Comment: ...and now you can't resize the comment textarea horizontally, only vertically. Kudos to the SO designers/developers.

Answer (score 5):

You may not want it here, but I want it here. I want to be able to resize my textareas, by fonts, zoom on the pages and scroll what I want.

You should not tell me how to use a browser on your website.

If you're afraid that it is going to break your design, relax. We know it. Nobody expect the website to work in every situation. When I use the drag handler, I do it to gain usablity, and I accept to break the design for this.

You can't control the client the user is using. You may be able to use `resize:none` but there are extensions for firefox, chrome and grease monkey that will bypass that anyway.

So rules of thumb: create a beautiful design and forget about dictating the way people are going to use the page. This is what people do in the desktop, where you actually have a hand on the client. Here you don't, we interpret your code the way we want.